# Calendar View not registering date unless clicked

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have a Calendar View set up like this

```
mCalendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    mNextBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.nextBtn1);

    mCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            string = (i1 + 1) + "/" +i2 + "/" + i;
            month = i1 + 1;
            day = i2;
            year = i;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("itemInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("ExpirationDate", string);
            editor.putInt("month", month);
            editor.putInt("year", year);
            editor.putInt("day", day);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
```

My problem with this is when I open the fragment with the calendar View it is highlighted on default the current date, but when I try to register it, it doesn't show the date. It only shows the date when you click on a date but doesn't work on the default date.

Solutions can either be removing the default highlight of the current date, or registering the date that is highlighted on defualt.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: So you're trying to override default date with saved date when you open the fragment? If so, you'd need to fetch your shared preferences value and set the `CalendarView`'s date using `CalendarView.setDate()` method.

Comment: Oh no sorry for my bad explanation, but basically when I open the fragment it has a date highlighted automatically and when I register without pressing any other date it doesnt register and leaves it as blank. But if I click on a date everything works perfectly @OmarSilva